# How to fix "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" in my Java program?

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I am very new to programming. My main goal is to write code that logs into a android app and does everything that you would have to do with your fingers. So far I've only got the app to open, now I'm stuck on entering the login information.

Here is my code -

```
package OpenOfferUpTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class OpenOfferUp {

AndroidDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void OpensOfferUp() throws MalformedURLException
{
File OfferUp = new File("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\OfferUp.apk");
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual Device");
cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
cap.setCapability("null", "OfferUp");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.offerup");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", 
"com.offerup.android.login.splash.LoginSplashActivity");

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

}
@Test
public void SimpleTest() {

driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/email_button")).click();

}

}
```

These are the main errors that show up in console -

`io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C`

`FAILED: OpensOfferUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`

`FAILED: SimpleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException`

I don't know how to fix any of these, I've been researching on how to fix these but I have no luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keywords: "ClassNotFoundException", "org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils".
Add the dependecy to your project which could be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1).